# AWS Lambda to list S3 bucket objects and subdirectories inside with file versioning

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I'm new to lambda and trying to list S3 bucket objects that has nested subdirectories , here is the structure:

```
- mybucket/folder1/project1/samplev1.txt
- mybucket/folder1/project1/sampleVer2.txt
- mybucket/folder2/
- mybucket/folder3/
```

here is my lambda code:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const s3 = new AWS.S3();

exports.handler = async (event) => {
  const allKeys = [];
  await getKeys({ Bucket: 'ru-mybucket' }, allKeys);
  console.log(allKeys)
  return allKeys;
};

async function getKeys(params, keys){
  const response = await s3.listObjectsV2(params).promise();
  response.Contents.forEach(obj => keys.push(obj.Key));

  if (response.IsTruncated) {
    const newParams = Object.assign({}, params);
    newParams.ContinuationToken = response.NextContinuationToken;
    await getKeys(newParams, keys); // RECURSIVE CALL
  }
}
```

The function list all objects keys inside my bucket with their nested subdirectories and files, The problem is how to list nested objects including their version, how can I achieve this? where to add (listObjectVersions) in my code to able loop over the objects which has versions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have done this [code](https://github.com/ns4lin4s/stackoverflow/tree/master/53109644) for you, in this example you can be seen the unit test and its implementation (apigateway).

Basically, i retrieved all keys from my bucket and then iterate them. Finally i got all objects, and i query *s3.listObjectsV2* passing two parameter the bucket and key.

**Below a pseudocode:**

```
s3.listObjectsV2({ Bucket: your_bucket, MaxKeys: 1000 }).forEach( element => {
   s3.listObjectVersions({ Bucket: your_bucket, Prefix: element.Key})
})
```

For that you can run the code sample, you must run the following command:

```
npm install
npm run deploy
```

For that you can test the code:

```
npm run test
```

Don't forget put your bucket:

```
./package.json
./tests/test.js
```

*Important: i used [serverless framework](http://serverless.com/) for this solution.*

Comment: Accepting  it as answer because it clearly lists objects and object versions and clearly explained, one slight change can be not to create a new bucket but to do listing operation on an existing bucket, also how do I deploy the serverless with different stages currently the npm run deploy deploy on dev stage only , what if I want prod or test stage? :)